# Expected number of unique transient states visited in an absorbing markov chain.

Tags: markov-chains

If I have an absorbing Markov chain represented as a transition matrix P - same notation as [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).

$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
Q & R \\
0 & I_r
\end{pmatrix}
$

How would I compute the expected number of unique transient states visited before arriving at the absorbing state?

I am assuming it would involve some sum of products over row probabilities in $Q$ but I am not sure.

-- For my specific case, I only have one terminating state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will of course depend on the initial state.
The probability of visiting state $j$ is the probability of ending up at $j$ in a modified Markov chain where you make $j$ absorbing.
Now sum this over all transient states $j$.